# How to alert user for document being opened on trying to change its metadata?

Tags: sharepoint-online, word

Currently, when a document is open in SharePoint, and you try to change or modify its properties/metadata, it doesn't allow it and it reverts to the original value. However, this scenario is bad for the overall UX since the user doesn't realize this issue is due to the document being opened. How can I display a message to alert the user that the document needs to be closed first?

PS. I've checked the console and it throws a 423 error on POST but nothing really shows up on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when you change the metadata of an opened document in the details panel, there is no OOB way to set an alert.

As a workaround, we can edit in the grid view or click Edit all in the details panel, both of which will prevent you from saving changes and pop up a reminder message:

[image]
[image]
[image]